# Unexpected behavior shown by search:search in marklogic

Tags: xml, search, full-text-search, xquery, marklogic

I am using `search:search` for searching the below kind of structure:

```
search:search(
  "",
  <options>
    <additional-query>
      {
        cts:and-query((
            cts:collection-query("A"),
            cts:not-query(cts:collection-query("B")),
            cts:not-query(cts:collection-query("C")),
            cts:and-query((
                cts:element-value-query(
                  xs:QName("uri"),
                  cts:search(collection("A"),
                    cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("uri"),
                      cts:search(collection("B"),
                        cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("uri"),
                          cts:search(collection("C"),cts:word-query("Hello"))/fn:base-uri()
                        )
                      )/fn:base-uri()
                    )
                  )/fn:base-uri()
                ),
                dls:documents-query()
            ))
        ))
      }
    </additional-query>
  </options>,1,10)
```

It gives 0 result.

However if I try this it gives required result

```
let $a :=
  cts:search(collection("A"),
    cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("uri"),
      cts:search(collection("B"),
        cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("uri"),
          cts:search(collection("C"),cts:word-query("Hello"))/fn:base-uri()
        )
      )/fn:base-uri()
    )
  )/fn:base-uri()
return
  search:search(
    "",
    <options>
      <additional-query>
        {
          cts:and-query((
              cts:collection-query("A"),
              cts:not-query(cts:collection-query("B")),
              cts:not-query(cts:collection-query("C")),
              cts:and-query((
                  cts:element-value-query(
                    xs:QName("uri"),
                    $a
                  ),
                  dls:documents-query()
              ))
          ))
        }
      </additional-query>
    </options>, 1, 10)
```

It solves the problem where some section is taken out and then passed in `search:search` options. 
Please look into it and help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't embed a `cts:query` directly in `search:options`.

Instead, try:

```
<search:options>
<search:additional-query>{...your cts:query here ...}</search:additional-query>
</search:options>
```

For more information, see:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/appendixb#id_98507

Also, if you want to use a subquery to retrieve values for use as criteria, you should create range indexes on the elements that are the source of the values and the target of the query and use a `cts:values()` lexicon lookup.  For more information, see:

http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:values

Hoping that helps,

Comment: i have already written <additional-query>, forgot to write above.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  On looking into it, I see that a subquery won't work in search:additional-query because it uses cts:query() to deserialize the additional query. I don't think the cts:query() constructor will execute a subquery. So executing the subquery separately is the right approach, though you might consider enabling the uris lexicon in the Admin UI and using cts:uris() instead of cts:search() for the subquery. See: http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:uris

Comment: Your query also shows a lot of joins across documents. Consider whether you could denormalize instead.

Comment: Thanks dave, but the thing is i cannot, the requirement is to log the above query so that an admin can use the above query and run it using xdmp:spawn